# Overwrite pdf while retaining URL in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm fairly new so forgive my question.

I am trying to overwrite a pdf file with a script, but would like to retain the same URL so that users can click the URL and get a dynamically changing pdf (rosters being filled).

`setContent(content)` only allows me to write a string to a file, not replace the pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Advanced Drive API to [overwrite the content](https://ctrlq.org/docs/20472-overwrite-existing-files-in-google-drive) of a file without changing the URL.

```
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("FILEID");
  Drive.Files.update({
    title: file.getName(), mimeType: file.getMimeType()
  }, file.getId(), blob);
```

Comment: Does this work if it's a container bound script? -- Thank you so much!

Comment: That will not matter.

Comment: I had to enable the Drive API.  Again, very new.  But it worked perfectly.  Thanks so much!

Comment: If your problem is resolved, please accept the answer.